# Javascript Change Image on Timer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to rotate a set of 6 images in javascript, not jquery. The first image shows up, but the rest of them don't rotate. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function rotatePic() {

var qutAd = document.getElementById("yumOreos");
var imgs = ["images/img1.png", "images/img2.png", "images/img3.png", "images/img4.png", "images/img5.png", "images/img6.png"];
var ad = 0;

qutAd.src = imgs[ad];

setInterval(function () {ad++;if (ad == imgs.length) {ad = 0;}}, 4000);
}  

</script>
</head>
<body onload="rotatePic()">
     <img id="yumOreos">
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `src` in the interval function as well.

```
setInterval(function () {
    ad++;
    if (ad == imgs.length) ad = 0;
    qutAd.src = imgs[ad];
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to change the index of the array, to change the source. So you can do this

```
setInterval(function () {if (ad == imgs.length) {ad = 0;} qutAd.src =imgs[ad++]}, 4000);
}
```